# Returning values based on matching strings and then expanding to other rows in same group

Tags: r

I have a dataset with 11,000 rows in the following format:

```
Case    Type    
A       x
A       y
A       z
B       a
B       b
B       z
```

...where Case and Type are both multiletter character strings. I want to add a new column of dummies for rows containing Type==x or y, which I can easily do using the following line of code:

```
df$quality <- ifelse(grepl("x|y", df$type), 1, 0)
```

This produces the following:

```
Case    Type    Quality
A       x       1
A       y       1
A       z       0
B       a       0
B       b       0
B       z       0
```

There are quite a few threads on how to do this. However, I couldn't find any that explain how do expand returned values across groups. Specifically, I'd like Quality==1 if *any* observations in a given Case contain x or y. The results should then look like:

```
Case    Type    Quality
A       x       1
A       y       1
A       z       1
B       a       0
B       b       0
B       z       0
```

...such that row 3 is also coded Quality==1 even though it doesn't contain Type x or y because another row in Case A does. The answer must be simple, but I'd be grateful for some help!

Comment: You can use any to create a scalar value per each group. `df %>% group_by(Case, Type) %>% mutate(Quality = any(grepl("x|y", type)))` And assign the value to variable, then it will be broadcasted within the group.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Similar to the idea of @Psidom, we can use base R method `ave`

```
df$Quality <- as.numeric(as.logical(ave(df$Type, df$Case, FUN = function(i)
                                                          any(grepl("x|y", i)))))

#    Case Type Quality
#1    A    x       1
#2    A    y       1
#3    A    z       1
#4    B    a       0
#5    B    b       0
#6    B    z       0
```

We can reduce this further, as commented by @thelatemail in comments,

```
df$Quality <- as.numeric(ave(grepl("[xy]", df$Type), df$Case, FUN=any))
```

Comment: Shrunken - `as.numeric(ave(grepl("[xy]", dat$Type), dat$Case, FUN=any))` or even `ave(grepl("[xy]", dat$Type), dat$Case, FUN=any)+0` if you want to abuse coercion of classes.

Comment: I'm having trouble seeing why ave() works here. Would it also work if "z" rows greatly outnumbered "x" and "y" rows in a given Case group?

Comment: @beddotcom yes, it will! Only one `x` or one `y` is enough to get all the 1's in the entire group.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `data.table`.  Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(df1)`), grouped by 'Case', we get the logical vector with `%in%` by checking whether the elements 'x', 'y' are `%in%` the 'Type' column.  If both of them needs to be there, use `all` (or else replace `all` with `any`), convert the logical vector to binary with `as.integer` and assign (`:=`) it to new column 'Quality'

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, Quality := as.integer(all(c('x', 'y') %in% Type)), by = Case]
df1
#   Case Type Quality
#1:    A    x       1
#2:    A    y       1
#3:    A    z       1
#4:    B    a       0
#5:    B    b       0
#6:    B    z       0
```

Or using the `OP's method

```
setDT(df1)[, Quality := as.integer(any(grepl("[xy]", Type))), by = Case]
```

---

Or with `dplyr`, we use the same methodology as in `data.table`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Case) %>%
    mutate(Quality = as.integer(all(c('x', 'y') %in% Type)))
    #mutate(Quality = as.integer(any(c('x', 'y') %in% Type)))
```

---

Or another `base R` option with `table`

```
tbl <- with(df1, table(Case, grepl("[x|y]", Type)))[,2]
transform(df1, Quality = +(Case %in% names(tbl[tbl!=0])))
```

Comment: Very transparent and lots of different options. Thanks!